# Is there a way to get new dwellers with higher than normal stats?

Tags: fallout-shelter

New dwellers seem to all start with very low starting stats.  Is there a way to get new dwellers with higher than normal stats?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is! Breed with two max-stat dwellers to get them super-babies.

[image]

[image]

As you notice, this is a level 1 CHILD.  The second photo is a super baby combined with a +3 stat pet.  The specific details to get these higher than normal stat children are as follows:

**"Super" Child Formula**

```
max = (male_total_special + female_total_special - 14) / 126

random_number = random(max / 4, max)

if random_number is greater than 0.95 the child will be legendary

if random_number is greater than 0.85 the child will be rare

otherwise the child will be normal
```

Notes:

- Parents' total SPECIAL must be 134 or higher to have a chance at a legendary child.
- Parents' total SPECIAL must be 122 or higher to have a chance at a rare child.
- Two fully maxed out parents (SPECIAL 140) will have a ~6.6% chance of producing a legendary child, and a ~13.3% chance of producing a rare child.
- Two maxed parents will produce a child with an Intelligence proficiency.

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/foshelter/comments/3jdiao/special_inheritance_and_super_children_vaulttec/)

Comment: Intelligence proficiency? Whats that

Comment: It is for meeting room requirements.  STR for power rooms, AGI for food rooms, PER for water rooms, etc.

A child with INT proficiency just means it will have INT as highest.

Comment: Although the latest version gives you even higher stats doing this when combined with + stat pets, it doesn't actually change the answers a whole lot so I'm just gonna stick in a comment instead.

Answer (score 3):

There is technically no way other than breeding 'super babies' or lunch boxes

Although the higher level your radio tower is and the higher the level of the dwellers in it, you have a better chance of getting dwellers with higher stats than normal