# Is it faster to run or dodge-roll?

Tags: achievements, god-of-war

I'm currently attempting to beat God of War 1 in under 5 hours for the *Speed of Jason McDonald* achievement.

When moving from from place to place, is it faster to run or dodge-roll?

Comment: I noticed you asked the question and answered it yourself almost immediately after - any particular reason you asked the question in the first place?

Comment: @B.S.Morganstein it's perfectly acceptable to do this. In fact, there's an option when asking a question that allows you to answer it at the same time as posting the question.

Comment: Right, I'm not contesting if you're allowed to do this (and I also haven't downvoted) - I'm just curious why you chose to do this, no malintent intended

Comment: @B.S.Morganstein I had the question myself and only found the answer after spending time researching achievement walkthroughs. I thought it would be helpful to others with the same question. As Vemonus pointed out, [self-answering is encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17845/351462)

Comment: A good question should be rewarded.  A good answer should also be rewarded.  There's no reason why one of the above stops applying simply because they came from the same person.

[I've done something like this before.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/241224/is-there-a-way-to-get-new-dwellers-with-higher-than-normal-stats)

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Gotcha, wasn't aware this type of behaviour is accepted/encouraged on Arqade. Thanks!

Comment: @Venomous I mean that said, it's also perfectly acceptable for the community to decide it's a bad question.  If the only person asking it _already knew the answer_, there's a decent chance the question doesn't really need to be asked.  (I personally didn't vote, just playing devils advocate for why that strategy may not work well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to playstationtrophies.org](http://www.playstationtrophies.org/game/god-of-war/trophy/11558-Speed-of-Jason-McDonald.html):

> **The fastest way to move in the game is roll with the [image: Right Stick] then immediately press [image: R1] (Hermes Rush). This
>   requires one upgrade into your blades first.**

Unfortunately, the guide doesn’t specify whether a regular dodge-roll without the *Hermes Rush* is faster than running.